# What is this plastic part on caliper brakes called?

Tags: rim-brake

What is this plastic part called and is it possible to get a replacement? It's commonly found on Shimano caliper brakes. I have a pair of brakes where one is missing both of these plastic bits and as a result, the brake makes creaking sounds when operated.

[image]

Comment: No idea of the name - but I routinely lost them off my vintage exage brakes.  Ended up using a long block of plastic, cutting "cheese slices" off the end, and then drilling a hole with a drill press.

Comment: Did you ever manage to source these, I’m working on a bicycle myself that has an Exage brake set, and one of these little black sleeves is broken...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With the information provided by Criggie's comment I was able to find an exploded diagram of the [Shimano Exage brake with a part list](https://si.shimano.com/pdfs/ev/EV-BR-A450-0859A.pdf).

That part is called (descriptively) a "Sleeve". It's part number 83E 0900
[image]

[image]

Searching for the part number reveals that Shimano uses that same part number on several different brakes.

I asked The Google as nicely as I could but found no replacement sleeves or brake rebuild kits available.
You are looking at:

1. Making your own per Criggie's comment
2. Scavenging sleeves from another caliper
3. Replacing the caliper
4. Living with the creaking sound
5. Duct tape?

Comment: A small piece of brake cable outer housing  might slip over the spring and be held in place by the spring tension.